# How to extract content from a json list?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

There is a long `string` value which contains a `json` list:

```
{"name":"jack","age":"38","city":"JP"},{"name":"lee","age":"42","city":"tjs"},{"name":"smith","age":"46","city":"kh"}
```

The objective is to extract info of `name`, so the result of this is `'jack,lee,smith'`.

I tried `get_json_object` but it returns `null`; I also tried `get_json_object` with `split` but still not worked...

Is there any suitable function in `Hive` that can implement this demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t as (select '{"name":"jack","age":"38","city":"JP"},{"name":"lee","age":"42","city":"tjs"},{"name":"smith","age":"46","city":"kh"}' as myjson)
select  get_json_object(concat('{"x":[',myjson,']}'),'$.x.name[*]')  as names
from    t
```

---

```
+------------------------+
|         names          |
+------------------------+
| ["jack","lee","smith"] |
+------------------------+
```

---

```
with t as (select '{"name":"jack","age":"38","city":"JP"},{"name":"lee","age":"42","city":"tjs"},{"name":"smith","age":"46","city":"kh"}' as myjson)
select  translate(get_json_object(concat('{"x":[',myjson,']}'),'$.x.name[*]'),'[]"','')  as names
from    t
```

---

```
+----------------+
|     names      |
+----------------+
| jack,lee,smith |
+----------------+
```

Comment: If rewrites it to `select  get_json_object(concat('{"x":[',myjson,']}'),'$.x[*].name')` then it works..  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You're welcome. P.s. This is a tested code and it seems both variation works (`'$.x.name[*]'` and `'$.x[*].name'`)